Expected behaviour using firestore.MergeAll?
I have a Go application, which uses Firestore to store data.
When updating a document, I'm passing a map of data to Firestore, but it behaves differently, depending on whether I'm using firestore.MergeAll, or firestore.Merge(...).
I have the following struct:
type User struct {
    Tokens Tokens
}
type Tokens struct {
    Sessions map[string]Token
}
type Token struct {
    Token string
    Expires int
}

In certain situation, I'd like to clear the Sessions property of any values, and I do it like so:
dataMap := map[string]interface{}{
    "Tokens": map[string]interface{}{
            "Sessions": map[string]interface{}{},
    },
}
_, err = c.ref.Doc(id).Set(ctx, dataMap, firestore.MergeAll)
// dataMap looks like so: map[Tokens:map[Sessions:map[]]]

When I do this, I get a Firestore error: firestore: missing WriteResult.
However, if I update it like below, it works as expected, and Sessions becomes an empty map inside Firestore...
dataMap := map[string]interface{}{
    "Tokens": map[string]interface{}{
            "Sessions": map[string]interface{}{},
    },
}
_, err = c.ref.Doc(id).Set(ctx, dataMap, firestore.Merge(firevault.FieldPath{"Tokens", "Sessions"}))
// dataMap looks like so: map[Tokens:map[Sessions:map[]]]

What is the difference between the two? Is there a way to achieve the same functionality with firestore.MergeAll, so that I don't always have to pass a FieldPath?

Please don't re-post old questions just to get more attention.  Doing so might get you banned from the site. Instead, focus on asking better questions to make it as easy as possible for others to help.
